# upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kdm

I have an issue with installing KDE on my Ubuntu 14.04.
I executed

```
apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

And tried to remove unity

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge unity unity-common unity-services
unity-lens-\* unity-scope-\* unity-webapps-\*
gnome-control-center-unity hud libunity-core-6\* libunity-misc4
libunity-webapps\* appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt\*
overlay-scrollbar\* activity-log-manager-control-center
firefox-globalmenu thunderbird-globalmenu libufe-xidgetter0
xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts webaccounts-extension-common
xul-ext-websites-integration gnome-control-center gnome-session
```

Next I chose KDM as default desktop manager.
But now every time I logging in on KDM login screen all I see is empty default KDE wallpaper.

Comment: Press **Ctrl+Alt+F1**, login and try a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop` Maybe you uninstalled something needed by KDE desktop.

Comment: I reinstalled it 2 times:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed some of removed tools, then switched to lightdm. Then I chosed KDE in login options. And switched back to KDM. It helps. But I think some of this steps was unnecessary